# issue with automatic level up system

Tags: node.js, mongodb, discord.js

So imp working on a level system with my database which its up and running and work but...

every time I execute a command it levels the person up even if they don't have the requirements for the level I want it so you have to have x amount of exp and y level to be able to level up to the next stage.

**This is the base of my code**

```
if (profileData.exp >= 500, profileData.level = 1){
    const response = await profileModel.findOneAndUpdate(
      {
        userID: message.author.id,
      },
      {
        $inc: {
          exp: -500,
          level: +1,
          bank: +500,
        },
      }
    );
    return message.channel.send(`${message.author.username}, Has Become Level 2 And Received 500 Gold Into There Bank`);
  }
```

if have tried this but it still did the same thing making the exp into - amounts and constant level up's

```
if (profileData.exp >= 500, profileData.level = 1){
    const response = await profileModel.findOneAndUpdate(
      {
        userID: message.author.id,
      },
      {
        $inc: {
          exp: -500,
          level: +1,
          bank: +500,
        },
      }
    );
    return message.channel.send(`${message.author.username}, Has Become Level 2 And Received 500 Gold Into There Bank`);
  } else if (profileData.exp <= 500){
continue;
}
```

I think the function I'm using is wrong form of doing it but I cant think how else to try to run the command so it only levels them up if they have 500 exp and level 1 so then when I add the next code for level 3 so it needs like x amount of exp and level 2 then they go to level 3 and lose that x amount of exp

Comment: That isn’t how to combine logical expressions—you might mean `&&` instead of the comma operator, and `=` is assignment, `==` is comparison.

Comment: thanks man I thought it looked weird when i first wrote it xD must of just not realised

Answer (score 0):

In your check, you are not comparing, you are setting the value.
Instead of: `if (profileData.exp >= 500, profileData.level = 1)`

Must be: `if (profileData.exp >= 500 && profileData.level === 1)`